# download file which redirects?

Tags: file, redirect, download

I've tried to search for this both on Google and StackOverFlow, but simply can't find what I'm looking for, it might be that it's simply not possible, but thought I would ask anyway.

I'm looking for a way to make a file redirect the user to another page, the user would download the file by clicking on a button.

It's for a Prestashop downloadable product, I'm trying to redirect the user to another part of our site (which isn't directly visible) to be able to view magazines, etc. in a viewer.

Now Prestashop is natively set up to download the file, which is what we don't want, hence the use of the viewer, but there is no way to simply provide a link to send the user to instead of a physical file, like a PDF or something. I can't really modify the button as its generated by Prestashop, and if I add a PDF file with the link in there it defeats te purpose as I dont want people having the link in a document (I know they can find it from their history and so on). Hence I thought it would be easier to do it with a document that redirects if possible.

So in short, is it possible to make a file that would send people to a certain web page once they open/download this file on/to their computer?

And if yes, how would one go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the user download an HTML file? If so, you can use "meta refresh" to redirect the user to your private page.

This does mean the unprotected link will be visible in downloaded HTML file - perhaps you can obfuscate this with JavaScript to make it a little more difficult for users to find your protected URL.

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76